# What is the difference between super(cls, instance) and super(cls, subclass)?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, super

Won’t `super(cls, instance)` and `super(cls, subclass)` both return the superclass of `cls`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is huge; `super()` with a type (class) second argument instead of an object (instance) gives you unbound methods, not bound methods (just like accessing those methods on a class would).

I'll explain first how `super()` works with an instance second argument.

`super()` inspects the MRO of `self`, finds the first argument (`type` or `supertype`) in the MRO, then finds the next object that has the requested attribute.

Demo:

```
>>> class BaseClass(object):
...     def foo(self): return 'BaseClass foo'
... 
>>> class Intermediary(BaseClass):
...     def foo(self): return 'Intermediary foo'
... 
>>> class Derived(Intermediary):
...     def foo(self): return 'Derived foo'
... 
>>> d = Derived()
>>> d.foo()
'Derived foo'
>>> super(Derived, d).foo
<bound method Intermediary.foo of <__main__.Derived object at 0x10ef4de90>>
>>> super(Derived, d).foo()
'Intermediary foo'
>>> super(Intermediary, d).foo()
'BaseClass foo'
>>> Derived.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Derived'>, <class '__main__.Intermediary'>, <class '__main__.BaseClass'>, <type 'object'>)
```

The MRO of `Derived` is `(Derived, Intermediary, BaseClass)`; `super()` finds this MRO by looking at the second argument, using `type(d).__mro__`. The search for `foo` starts at the *next* class after the first argument given.

The `foo()` method is bound here, you can just call it.

If you give `super()` a *type* as the second argument, then it'll use the MRO of that type, e.g. instead of using `type(instance).__mro__` it just goes for `type.__mro__`. However it then has no instance to bind the methods to. `super(supertype, type).foo` is **just the (unbound) function object**:

```
>>> super(Intermediary, Derived).foo
<function BaseClass.foo at 0x106dd6040>
>>> super(Intermediary, Derived).foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
>>> super(Intermediary, Derived).foo(d)
'BaseClass foo'
```

To call `.foo()` I have to explicitly pass in a `self` argument.

(In Python 2, the above would return a `foo` *unbound method* object instead of a function, but the principle is the same).

The method returned is also, again, from the next class in the MRO chain; `BaseClass.foo` was returned there.

This is down to the `function.__get__` method (i.e. the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), responsible for binding), as it returns itself (or, in Python 2, an unbound method) when passed a class to bind to. (For [`classmethod` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), `__get__` does return a bound object when passed in a class).

So, TL;DR, for methods `super(type, object)` returns a *bound* method, `super(supertype, type)` returns unbound methods. The goal was to make it possible to store this object as a class-private attribute to avoid having to keep looking up the class object, see [How to use super() with one argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190185/how-can-i-use-super-with-one-argument-in-python). It's use-case has been obsoleted entirely in Python 3 so it is [slated for deprecation](https://discuss.python.org/t/is-it-time-to-deprecate-unbound-super-methods/1833).

Comment: I believe you but I did not find any information about this on official documents.  Is there any official explain about this?

Comment: @KramerLi: It's all covered in the [`super()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

Comment: @KramerLi: I recently 'ported' the implementation to Python to answer another question: [What is the type of the super object returned by super()?](//stackoverflow.com/a/44994572). Would that help in understanding?

Comment: Thanks, your answer here already very clear.  The most important info to me from your answer is that "super() with a type (class) second argument instead of an object (instance) gives you unbound methods".  I think that this is a very important info that the python official documents should mention. But I really did not find this kind of information on the official documents(I also read the link you provided). So I am just wondering did I missed anything from the official doc ?

Comment: @KramerLi: I perhaps put more emphasis on that than needed, but I do see the documentation is not as clear on that the same binding rules apply as normal instance and class attribute access.

Comment: @Maggyero: sorry, but I had to roll back those edits. You changed huge swathes of my answer, and I spent a lot of headscratching trying to find a reference I knew was around somewhere but was removed by your edit. I don’t really have time to review right now if there is anything I want to salvage. Please don’t edit my posts to this extent.

Comment: Yes my multiple edits ended up in a big change, so I should have posted a separate answer. That is what I did eventually.

Answer (score 0):

`super(cls, instance).attr` inspects the M.R.O. of the class of `instance` (i.e. `instance.__class__.__mro__`), looks up the *next* class after `cls` in the M.R.O. that has an attribute `attr`, and returns the result of `attr.__get__(instance, instance.__class__)` if it has a `__get__` method or returns `attr` if it has no `__get__` method. This case is used in *functions*:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def f(self): return 'A.f'
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def f(self): return 'B.f ' + super(B, self).f()
... 
>>> B().f()
'B.f A.f'
```

`super(cls, subclass).attr` inspects the M.R.O. of `subclass` (i.e. `subclass.__mro__`), looks up the *next* class after `cls` in the M.R.O. that has an attribute `attr`, and returns the result of `attr.__get__(None, subclass)` if it has a `__get__` method or returns `attr` if it has no `__get__` method. This case is used in [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```py
>>> class A:
...     @classmethod
...     def f(cls): return 'A.f'
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     @classmethod
...     def f(cls): return 'B.f ' + super(B, cls).f()
... 
>>> B.f()
'B.f A.f'
```

For function attributes, `super(cls, instance).attr` returns a *bound method* of `instance`, while `super(cls, subclass).attr` returns a *function*:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def f(self): return 'A.f'
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def f(self): return 'B.f'
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.f
<bound method B.f of <__main__.B object at 0x10e7d3fa0>>
>>> B.f
<function B.f at 0x10e7ea790>
>>> b.f()
'B.f'
>>> B.f(b)
'B.f'
>>> super(B, b).f
<bound method A.f of <__main__.B object at 0x10e7d3fa0>>
>>> super(B, B).f
<function A.f at 0x10e7ea700>
>>> super(B, b).f()
'A.f'
>>> super(B, B).f(b)
'A.f'
```

For [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) attributes, `super(cls, instance).attr` and `super(cls, subclass).attr` return a *bound method* of respectively `instance.__class__` and `subclass`:

```py
>>> class A:
...     @classmethod
...     def f(cls): return 'A.f'
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     @classmethod
...     def f(cls): return 'B.f'
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.f
<bound method B.f of <class '__main__.B'>>
>>> B.f
<bound method B.f of <class '__main__.B'>>
>>> b.f()
'B.f'
>>> B.f()
'B.f'
>>> super(B, b).f
<bound method A.f of <class '__main__.B'>>
>>> super(B, B).f
<bound method A.f of <class '__main__.B'>>
>>> super(B, b).f()
'A.f'
>>> super(B, B).f()
'A.f'
```