# How to use super() with one argument?

Tags: python, super, python-descriptors

While reading the Python documentation on [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), I stumbled on the following statement:

> If the second argument is omitted, the super object returned is unbound.

What does ‘unbound’ mean and how to use `super()` with one argument?

Comment: See [Class method differences in Python: bound, unbound and static](http://stackoverflow.com/q/114214) for what it means for something to be bound or unbound.

Answer (score 36):

Python function objects are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and Python uses the descriptor protocol to *bind* functions to an instance. This process produces a *bound method*.

Binding is what makes the 'magic' `self` argument appear when you call a method, and what makes a `property` object automatically call methods when you try to use the property as an attribute on instances.

`super()` with two arguments invokes the same descriptor protocol when you try to use it to look up methods on parent classes; `super(Foo, self).bar()` will traverse the `Foo` parent classes until an attribute `bar` is found, and if that is an object that is a descriptor, it will be bound to `self`. Calling `bar` then calls the bound method, which in turn calls the function passing in the `self` argument as `bar(self)`.

To do this, the `super()` object stores both the class (first argument) and `self` (second argument) to bind with, *and* the type of the `self` argument as the attributes `__thisclass__`, `__self__` and `__self_class__` respectively:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self):
...         return 'bar on Foo'
... 
>>> class Spam(Foo):
...     def bar(self):
...         return 'bar on Spam'
... 
>>> spam = Spam()
>>> super(Spam, spam)
<super: <class 'Spam'>, <Spam object>>
>>> super(Spam, spam).__thisclass__
<class '__main__.Spam'>
>>> super(Spam, spam).__self__
<__main__.Spam object at 0x107195c10>
>>> super(Spam, spam).__self_class__
<class '__main__.Spam'>
```

When looking up attributes, the `__mro__` attribute of the `__self_class__` attribute is searched, starting one position past the position of `__thisclass__`, and the results are bound.

`super()` with just *one* argument will have its `__self__` and `__self_class__` attributes set to `None` and cannot do lookups *yet*:

```
>>> super(Spam)
<super: <class 'Spam'>, NULL>
>>> super(Spam).__self__ is None
True
>>> super(Spam).__self_class__ is None
True
>>> super(Spam).bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

The object *does* support the descriptor protocol, so you can *bind* it just like you can bind a method:

```
>>> super(Spam).__get__(spam, Spam)
<super: <class 'Spam'>, <Spam object>>
>>> super(Spam).__get__(spam, Spam).bar()
'bar on Foo'
```

This means you can store such an object *on a class* and use it to traverse to parent methods:

```
>>> class Eggs(Spam):
...     pass
... 
>>> Eggs.parent = super(Eggs)
>>> eggs = Eggs()
>>> eggs.parent
<super: <class 'Eggs'>, <Eggs object>>
>>> eggs.parent.bar()
'bar on Spam'
```

The primary use case would be to avoid having to repeat the class each time with the two-argument form of `super()`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        # class-private attribute so subclasses don’t clobber one another
        setattr(cls, f'_{cls.__name__}__parent', super(cls))

    def bar(self):
        return 'bar on Foo'

class Spam(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        return 'spammed: ' + self.__parent.bar()
```

but that breaks when using a class method (since `cls.__parent` won’t bind) and has been superseded by Python 3’s `super()` with zero arguments which picks up the class from a closure:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        return 'bar on Foo'

class Spam(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        return 'spammed: ' + super().bar()
```

Comment: Extremely useful answer as this behavior is undocumented, thank you Martijn.

Comment: Is there a built in way to traverse the MRO of the class and return unbounded results?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper: just iterate over the [class `__mro__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__mro__#class.__mro__), then access the class namespace directly (e.g. [`vars(classobject)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) gives you that namespace, a dictionary).

Comment: Great answer!
But what is a practical usage of `super` with only one argument?
I have `Bar` class with `bar = 'bar'` class attribute and `super(Bar) .bar` giving `AttributeError`.

Comment: @ДавидШико read the whole answer, I cover that explicitly

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can also do this:

```
>>> class Eggs(Spam):
...     grand_parent = super(Spam)
... 
>>> eggs = Eggs()
>>> eggs.grand_parent.bar()
'bar on Foo'
```

I discovered this because I wanted to avoid creating class attribute outside of the class, and I was unable to do this:

```
>>> class Eggs(Spam):
...     parent = super(Eggs)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<stdin>", line 2, in Eggs
NameError: name 'Eggs' is not defined
```

However, you can use instance attribute to achieve it:

```
>>> class Eggs(Spam):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.Parent = super(Eggs).__get__(self, Eggs)
...
>>> eggs = Eggs()
>>> eggs.parent.bar()
'bar on Spam'
```