# how to use 'super(type)' in Python?AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'test'

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
class A(object):
   def test(self): pass
class B(A): pass
```

my question is when I run super(B).test, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'test'
```

I saw the python document: "super(type) -> unbound super object", why it didn't work? I hope someone could give an example of using "super(type)" corretly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really odd thing to do, and as zebo said, there's no need to use `super` here, calling `test` on an instance of `B` will call the `test` method inherited from `A`. Demo:

```
class A(object):
   def test(self):
       print('In test', self)

class B(A): pass

b = B()
b.test()
```

**output**

```
In test <__main__.B object at 0xb715fb6c>
```

However, it *is* possible to use `super`, if you pass it an instance of `B`:

```
super(B, b).test()
```

or

```
super(B, B()).test()
```

Both of these lines give the same output as the previous code. And this all works in both Python 2 & 3. (Of course you need to do `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2 to access the `print` function).

Comment: Why does it only work with instances though? None of `super(A).test`, `super(B).test` and `super(A, B).test` work. EDIT: Turns out `super(B, B).test` works. I'll try to wrap my head around this one...

Comment: @Rawing. Weird. Neither `super(A, B).test()` nor  `super(B, B).test()` work for me on Python 2.6.6 or 3.6.0. The former raises `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'test'`, the latter raises `TypeError: unbound method test() must be called with B instance as first argument (got nothing instead)` in Python 2 and `TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` in Python 3.

Comment: @Rawing The 2 arg form of `super` is either `super(type, obj)`, where `obj` is an instance (derived from) `type`, or `super(type, type2)`. But really they should only be used inside a method. In Python 3, deep magic is used to allow `super` to do its stuff. Take a look at the excellent [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19608134/4014959) by Zero Piraeus & Martijn Pieters.

Comment: Of course you can't call it without an instance, but `super(B, B).test` lets you at least access the `test` method of `A`. I expected `super(B)` to work like that, but it doesn't, so now I'm confused what the point of unbound super objects is...

Comment: @Rawing More wisdom from the ninja: [How can I use super() with one argument in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30190341/4014959)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to know how to use super() with one argument, i.e. super(type), could you show me an example?

Comment: @Jay I think Martijn has covered that topic well in the last answer I linked to. And in Python 3, the most common use of `super` is to call it with no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to invoke test, you do not need to use super here.

```
b = B()
b.test()
```

The keyword [super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) in python is usually used in inner class.
Thanks for @PM 2Ring's tip.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is  how to use "super(type)", could you give me an example? thanks