# pyhon3 dynamically create methods from parent class

Tags: python, python-3.7

Let's say I have a class defined like this:

```
classA():
    def do_one():
        print("one")
    def do_two():
        print("two")
    def some_other():
        print("other")
```

I want to create a derived class and automatically define every method from the parent class that starts with `do`

I tried this:

```
class B(A):
    pass

for m in dir(A):
    if m[0:3] == "do_":
        def dm(self):
            print("somebething before")
            getattr(super(),m)()
        dm.__name__ = m
        setattr(B,m,dm)
```

But i'm getting this error: `RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found`
Also is there a non-so-hacky/pytonic way of achieving this?

Comment: Just to be more clear about the situation, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a class wrapper that essentially overrides a number of (similar) methods from the parent, and those methods would consist in doing some stuff (the same for every method) and then calling the parent method

Comment: If going this route, I'd use the __init__ method to modify the instance's 'do_xxx' attributes so that super() etc. behave normally but it is probably cleaner to abstract further. Perhaps add the "actor" as a 'do' attribute and then wrap it for B. That way you would use e.g. `self.do.one()` rather than `self.do_one`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `super()` without arguments outside a class definition. In order to perform lookups `super()` [needs two arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30190341/15187728). Additionally, the definition of `dm` needs to be wrapped in another function. Otherwise, when it is executed the value of `m` will be taken from the global scope.

Putting this together, the following should work:

```
class A():
    def do_one(self):
        print("one")

    def do_two(self):
        print("two")

    def some_other(self):
        print("other")


class B(A):
    pass


for m in dir(B):
    if m[0:3] == "do_":

        def redef(m):
            def dm(self):
                print("something before")
                getattr(super(B, self), m)()

            return dm

        setattr(B, m, redef(m))
```

If you run:

```
x = B()
x.do_one()
x.do_two()
x.some_other()
```

It will give:

```
something before
one
something before
two
other
```