# I have an error "BasePage.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" while trying to trigger super().__init__ in inherited class

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make correct selenium automation using PageObject Model
I have BasePage class with `__init__(self, driver)` method where I call open() method that opens page using driver:

```
class BasePage:
    page_url = "placeholder"

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        open()

    def open(self):
        self.driver.get(self.page_url)
```

Then I have inherited class `LoginPage(BasePage)` where I wanna have additional variable for login button to use it in other LoginPage class methods. To use `driver` variable and open page to find login button on it, I have to use `super().__init__(self, driver)` in LoginPage's own '**init**' method:

```
class LoginPage(BasePage):
    page_url = os.getenv("LOGIN_URL")

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(self, driver)
        self.login_button = self.driver.find_element(*LoginPageLocators.LOGIN_BUTTON)
```

But somehow I get `TypeError: BasePage.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` error. Could anyone help?

Comment: `super().__init__(driver)`, you don't pass `self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm not able to reproduce the code due to some missing variables, I will use the following equivalent code:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super().__init__(self, arg)


obj = Child("value")
```

This raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/to/file.py", line 9, in <module>
    obj = Child("value")
  File "C:/path/to/file.py", line 7, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, arg)
TypeError: Base.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Because the error message talks about about arguments, let's use a basic debug operator to investigate the problem:

```py
from functools import wraps

def debug(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Called {func.__qualname__}({', '.join(list(map(repr, args)) + [key + '=' + repr(value) for key, value in kwargs.items()])}).")
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"{func.__qualname__} returned {value!r}.")
        return value
    return wrapper

class Base:
    @debug
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

class Child(Base):
    @debug
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super().__init__(self, arg)
        
obj = Child("value")
```

Output (excluding exception):

```
Called Child.__init__(<__main__.Child object at 0x000002261C976390>, 'value').
Called Base.__init__(<__main__.Child object at 0x000002261C976390>, <__main__.Child object at 0x000002261C976390>, 'value').
```

As you can see, `Base.__init__` was called with twice the same `Child` object as an argument. This means that `super` has already provided the self argument and we don't have to do it anymore. If we replace:

```py
super().__init__(self, arg)
```

with:

```py
super().__init__(arg)
```

the code works perfectly. The same is valid for your code:

You should replace

```py
super().__init__(self, driver)
```

with

```py
super().__init__(driver)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190185/how-to-use-super-with-one-argument) for more information on why this happens.

I have also noticed that you call `open()`. Because `open` is a built-in function, this won't raise a `NameError`, but it will raise a `TypeError` because open requires at least one argument. Because this code is not yet reached due to the other error, this doesn't raise an error yet.

I think you intended to call `self.open()` instead.